# Prove the boundedness condition

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_n\geq 0.$ Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges if and only if the sequence of partial sums $(s_n)=(\sum_{j=1}^na_j)$ is bounded. Use the axiom of completeness or one of its consequences to prove this result.

So the axiom of completeness says that there are no 'gaps' in the real number line. But I don't know where to USE the axiom of completeness

Comment: $a_n\geq 0$ as stated in the question <--- a reply to a deleted comment

Comment: The first step towards *using* something is to *state* it. Not the thing you were told it kind-of means, not the thing you think it means: the actual statement.

Comment: The axiom is: Every non-empty subset of the reals that is bounded above has a least upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

The axiom of completeness implies that a nonempty set of real numbers which is bounded above has a least upper bound.

In your case the sequence of partial sum is nonempty and the supernum happens to be the limit.

You use definition of the least upper bound to prove your statement.